# Python 3 Clue Board Game (AI Shortest Path to Door)

Tags: python, python-3.x

One of the components that I need for the AI for the board game Clue is for the AI to find the shortest path between its current position and a specific door. 
My board is represented as a as a list containing 676 tuples (Each tuple has an x and y coordinate... (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), ... (26, 26)). I am completely stumped on figuring out how to get the AI to determine the quickest path to a door.

For those of you that do not know this is a clue game board...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVFoE.jpg

So to get to the point what I need is to input a x, y position in the form of a tuple and then I need the program to return the positions (in the form of tuples) that the AI will take.

Keep in mind that there are obstacles that the AI needs to avoid. (Specifically the cells that are not the yellowish pathway color)

For example:
AI is on cell 10, 10
End Goal 12, 13
Return [(10, 10), (11, 10), (12, 10), (12, 11), (12, 12), (12, 13)]

If you can help me anyway then I will be so thankful. I have looked everywhere for answers, but no "solution" returns the optimal and quickest path.

Comment: Have you tried anything? where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

You could save all solutions as coordinate lists to a dictionary, then find the shortest list in the dictionary. This could be multiple answers, so you could either use python's random module, or prioritize the first one found in the dictionary.